# Linux Partition is not shown by fdisk

Tags: installation, grub2, fdisk

I want to reinstall my grub boot loader but when I boot Ubuntu from USB and type
**sudo fdisk -l**  on terminal, it don't show my linux partion which I need to know to reinstall grub.I had used this method several times in past and it worked great for me.But today fdisk is not showing linux partiions.
SNAPSHOTS ARE GIVEN BELOW:
[image: Terminal Output]
[image: Gparted Output]
[image: Disk Utility]
[image: Disk Management Windows Output]

Answer (score 1):

Either you don't have Ubuntu installed, or it is a Wubi install, and is entirely contained within a file in your Windows partition.

Comment: No I had Ubuntu installed on different partition and not as wubi install  as you can see in last snapshot(marked green), also gparted show the partition as unallocated space.

Comment: @KashmirHackers, in that case you seem to have deleted it.

Comment: but I only reinstalled my windows 7 with the help of repair disk, and I have done it before many times, but don't know why this time my reinstallation of windows 7 wiped out my Ubuntu partitions.